# How to open chrome as a certain user

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I am making a batch file that opens chrome to a specific page. I started with the

```
start
```

command by writing the line:

```
start http://www.google.com
```

I then added the specific browser chrome to open the tab.

```
start chrome.exe http://www.google.com
```

However i noticed that google chrome has an "account feature" that lets you browse as different accounts. I tested everything i could guess but i can find a way to get chrome to open the tab as a specific user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1"` to start chrome under a specific *Chrome user*.

Take a look at this article over on Superuser: [Resolved Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile)

There was a very interesting response over there about how Chrome has a neat feature of adding desktop shortcuts for specific users in the Chrome User settings.